# Innerjoin With Where Clause?

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

```
$InnerJoinQuery = $STD->query("
        SELECT Users.ID, Users.Username, Users.Password, UserInformation.LastName, UserInformation.Firstname, UserInformation.DOB
        FROM Users AS Users 
        INNER JOIN UserInformation AS UserInformation 
        ON Users.ID = UserInformation.UserID WHERE Users.Username=".$_SESSION['real_name']."");
        $InnerJoinArray = $InnerJoinQuery->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

My Above code is causing an error. It works up to the point of my `WHERE` Clause.

`WHERE Users.Username=".$_SESSION['real_name']."`

How can i Impliment this into my innerjoin?

Update:

```
$InnerJoinQuery = $STD->query("
        SELECT Users.ID, Users.Username, Users.Password, UserInformation.LastName, UserInformation.Firstname, UserInformation.DOB
        FROM Users
        INNER JOIN UserInformation
        ON Users.ID = UserInformation.UserID WHERE Users.Username = '".$_SESSION['real_name']."'");
        $InnerJoinArray = $InnerJoinQuery->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);



        $_SESSION['UID'] = $InnerJoinArray['ID'];
        $_SESSION['Password'] = $InnerJoinArray['Password'];
        $_SESSION['Firstname'] = $InnerJoinArray['Firstname'];
        $_SESSION['LastName'] = $InnerJoinArray['LastName'];
        $_SESSION['DOB'] = $InnerJoinArray['DOB'];
            print_r($_SESSION);
```

This returns:

> Array ( [real_name] => inhumaneslayer [Password] => [UID] => [Firstname] => [LastName] => [DOB] => )

Which is not expected.

When I change my Query To:

```
$InnerJoinQuery = $STD->query("
        SELECT Users.ID, Users.Username, Users.Password, UserInformation.LastName, UserInformation.Firstname, UserInformation.DOB
        FROM Users
        INNER JOIN UserInformation
        ON Users.ID = UserInformation.UserID WHERE Users.Username = 'inhumaneslayer'");
```

I get the expected result:

> Array ( [real_name] => inhumaneslayer [Password] => PASSWORDHIDDEN [UID] => 5 [Firstname] => xx [LastName] => xx [DOB] => DOBHIDDEN )

Which is expected.

**I am unsetting session by `unset($_SESSION);` prior to changing the SQL**

Comment: This code is possibly vulnerable to second-order SQL injection. Please parametrize your queries.

Comment: Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enclose the string in quotes:

```
... Users.Username='".$_SESSION['real_name']."'")
```

Also - you need to escape the variable properly. How exactly you would do that - depends on the DB library you use. In your case it's http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

```
... Users.Username='". $STD->real_escape_string($_SESSION['real_name']) ."'")
```

But better - learn how to use prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

```
$stmt = $STD->query("
        SELECT Users.ID, Users.Username, Users.Password, UserInformation.LastName, UserInformation.Firstname, UserInformation.DOB
        FROM Users AS Users 
        INNER JOIN UserInformation AS UserInformation 
        ON Users.ID = UserInformation.UserID WHERE Users.Username=?");

$stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['real_name']);

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

$InnerJoinArray = $result->fetch_array();
```

Comment: Returning blank, when I change to `WHERE Users.Username='test'");` it returns a result, `$_SESSION['real_name']` is properly being set

Comment: @user1968541: I'm not sure I understand what you're talking about

Comment: @user1968541: `var_dump($_SESSION['real_name']);` and copy paste the result here

Comment: @user1968541: I only see the difference in the case. Change the case and see if it changes the result

Answer (score 0):

Using @zerkms Comment I Done His changes and: Returning blank, when I change to WHERE Users.Username='test'"); it returns a result, $_SESSION['real_name'] is properly being set

Answer (score -1):

you're forgetting the (single/double) quote around your string (you are looking for a string, not integer?)

Try: `".... WHERE Users.Username='".$_SESSION['real_name']."'")`

otherwise, the way you had it, it would search for

`WHERE Users.Username=some_string` (instead of `Users.Username='some_string'`)which will return an error since `some_string` is a string and it needs to be wrapped in quotes

---

If still no results:

try putting your query in a variable `$query = "SELECT Users .....";`

Then `echo $query` and see what your $_SESSION variable is actually producing. Without knowing that, there's not much more I can do to help.

Comment: "or apostrophe" --- what do you mean by that?

Comment: @zerkms ya sorry i've been listening to alot of Zappa... changed it

Comment: Using @zerkms Comment I Done His changes and:  
Returning blank, when I change to WHERE Users.Username='test'"); it returns a result, $_SESSION['real_name'] is properly being set